# how to pass data between two fragments destination If I tap a menu in navigation controller?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to use navigation controller. I have a bottom navigation view. that located on my MainActivity, and it is initiated using the code below on :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var navController : NavController
    lateinit var logoHeaderImageView : ImageView
    var toolbarMenu : Menu? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        logoHeaderImageView = findViewById(R.id.header_lakuin_image_view)

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_main_host_fragment)



        setupBottomNavMenu(navController)
        setupActionBar(navController)



    }

    fun setupBottomNavMenu(navController: NavController) {
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottom_navigation_view,navController)
    }

    fun setupActionBar(navController: NavController) {
        setSupportActionBar(main_activity_toolbar)
        main_activity_toolbar.title = ""


        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                // set some destination as the top hierarchy destination, to make the up button doesn't show.
                R.id.destination_home,
                R.id.destination_order,
                R.id.destination_favourite,
                R.id.destination_cart,
                R.id.destination_profile

            ))

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(main_activity_toolbar,navController,appBarConfiguration)
    }


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main_toolbar, menu)
        toolbarMenu = menu
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }




}
```

here is the look of my bottom navigation view:
[image]

So I want to pass data from my `HomeFragment` (destination home) to `OderFragment` (destination order). I usually using bundle or safeArgs to pass data like the code below:

```
var bundle = bundleOf("amount" to amount)
view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.confirmationAction, bundle)
```

but I don't know where to place that code, If I want to pass data from my `HomeFragment` to `OderFragment`

Comment: is it `BottomNavigation` or custom view?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottom_navigation_view,navController)` (or, if you're using the `navigation-ui-ktx` Kotlin extension `bottom_navigation_view.setupWithNavController(navController)`), you can't pass any custom arguments to destinations - an important part of global navigation is that they always take you to the same screen in the same state.

Generally, you should be holding data like the current amount separately from Navigation arguments - whether it is in a persisted database, SharedPreferences, or some other location that would survive process death, allowing users to continue with what they're doing even after restarting their phone, etc.

However, if you must use Navigation arguments for this, you can set the default argument for your destination ahead of time (i.e., whenever your amount changes):

```
NavDestination orderDestination = navController.graph.findNode(R.id.destination_order)
orderDestination.addArgument("amount", NavArgument.Builder()
    .setType(NavType.FloatType)
    .setDefaultValue(amount)
    .build())
```

Afterwards, your `BottomNavigationView` triggering `R.id.destination_order` will automatically include that argument, along with your new `amount` value, by default.

Comment: thank you very much, but I can't access findDestionation method like in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LR69.png

Comment: @sarah - corrected the code, it should have been `navController.graph.findNode`

Comment: This is indeed an excellent answer, I initially tried supplying a custom OnNavigationItemSelectedListener as suggested elsewhere but shortly realized it's messy to deal with NavigationUI internals (to replicate behavior) and this is much better.

Comment: Off all the solutions elsewhere, this one worked perfectly when passing a Model as a parcelable. Thank you very much... :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a shared ViewModel between fragments:

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val selected = MutableLiveData<Item>()

    fun select(item: Item) {
        selected.value = item
    }
}

class MasterFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var itemSelector: Selector

    private lateinit var model: SharedViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        model = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener { item ->
            // Update the UI
        }
    }
}

class DetailFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var model: SharedViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        model = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
        model.selected.observe(this, Observer<Item> { item ->
            // Update the UI
        })
    }
}
```

more information can be found here:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Answer (score 1):

Just like that:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("myname","Hussnain")
    return when(item.itemId){
        R.id.aboutFragment ->{
            navController.navigate(R.id.aboutFragment,bundle)
            return true
    }else -> {
            NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item,navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Navigation:

```
 <fragment android:id="@+id/aboutFragment"
 android:name="com.cinderellaman.general.ui.fragments
 .AboutFragment"
  android:label="about_fragment"
  tools:layout="@layout/about_fragment">
  <argument android:name="myname" app:argType="string"/>
</fragment>
```

fragment:

```
val args: AboutFragmentArgs by navArgs()
name.text = args.myname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Post data:
Fragment fragment = new OderFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("key", "value");
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

Receive data:
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
            if (bundle != null) {
                myInt = bundle.getString("key");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Call Nav contoller from current fragment. And pass data as a bundle

Ex:
First fragment -
val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("crs",crs); //This is the passing parameter
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_Classes_to_AddUpdateStudents,bundle)
//Amend your parameter as a second argument

Second fragment -
crs = arguments?.getString("crs").toString() 
//Retrieve the data as u usually do with an activiy
```